# After bootrec.exe /fixmbr -> missing operating system

Tags: boot, multi-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-7

I need the SP1 on Windows 7, but I get always an error when I want to install it.
I read that it is because I have a dual boot Windows 7 + Ubuntu. And after installing Ubuntu, GRUB2 overwrote the Windows 7 mbr or something like that.

So I wanted to fix it. I read that you should boot Windows 7 with a DVD, then click on Windows repair and then in the cmd write the command "bootrec.exe /fixmbr" to recover the Windows mbr and delete GRUB2. But after restarting my PC -> no GRUB2, but also "missing operating systrem".

So what should I do? I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: But I think it's because of GRUB2.

Answer (score 0):

`bootrec.exe /mbr` is not sufficient. You must first use `diskpart` to mark the partition containing Windows 7 bootloader as active. It is probably called System Reserved.

But why doing it manually? Windows 7 DVD has a "Startup Repair" feature that does all this automatically.

[image: System Recovery Options]

Comment: This didn't work because Startup Repair says that there is no Disk image or something like that, it couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try Running the following code:

```
bootrec.exe/FixBoot
```

And then run:

```
bootrec.exe/FixMBR
```

This should work because this is what i normally use to boot into windows after removing Linux Installations.

Comment: This didn't work, because the first command responded that there is no image or disk to fix.